# Postfix - private/rewrite

Tags: postfix

Postfix is giving me this error on startup:

```
Oct  8 16:59:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[23917]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Oct  8 17:00:57 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24106]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  8 17:00:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24117]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  8 17:01:00 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24122]: fatal: Cannot flush mail queue - mail system is down
Oct  8 17:01:28 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: database /etc/aliases.db is older than source file /etc/aliases
Oct  8 17:01:28 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Oct  8 17:01:28 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: connect from spring-chicken-ah.twitter.com[199.16.156.147]
Oct  8 17:01:29 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:01:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:01:49 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #3 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:01:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #4 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:09 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #5 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:19 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #6 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:29 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:49 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:02:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
Oct  8 17:03:09 cheese-ubuntu postfix/smtpd[24145]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/rewrite: Connection refused
```

Postconf - n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = host.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Please help - this is urgent

Comment: Run `postalias /etc/aliases`. Then restart Postfix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back and re-read your error messages.

```
Oct  8 17:00:57 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24106]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  8 17:00:59 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24117]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Oct  8 17:01:00 cheese-ubuntu postfix/postqueue[24122]: fatal: Cannot flush mail queue - mail system is down
```

Says it all.  Your mail service isn't running properly to begin with.

Keep in mind, SysV init scripts do *state management*, not *process management*.  State management deals with the state of the system; process management is a subset of state management that is only concerned with oversight of long-running processes.

It is entirely possible to "start" the service, SysV marks the service as running, but the service will keel over dead.  So now you have the service "running" but it really isn't.  Stop the service, then start it, then watch the logs:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix stop ; /etc/init.d/postfix start ; tail -f -n100 /var/log/messages
```

Look for messages about postfix starting up, and what it is doing.  Post some of those results here.